# image_number error in matlab loop

Tags: matlab

can anyone help me? I have a loop as follows:

```
global im2
axes(handles.axes4);

for i= 1:40

cd(strcat('C:\Users\JerryFarla\Desktop\images test\yale faces\ImageZ\',num2str(i)));
c = imread('1 (1).jpg');

%subplot(222)  
axes(handles.axes4)
imshow(c);

set(handles.image_number,'String',strcat('Processed now --->',num2str(i)))   

end
img=imread('C:\Users\JerryFarla\Desktop\images test\yale faces\ImageZ\1 (*).jpg');
a=img;
axes(handles.axes5)
imshow(img)
```

my issue is that it gives  me the error

> ??? Reference to non-existent field 'image_number'.
>
> Error in ==> testgui1>pushbutton2_Callback at 270
>       set(handles.image_number,'String',strcat('Processed now --->',num2str(i)))

Is the error due to my version of matlab (i'm using the R2011a version)? 
If yes, is there any function with the same purpose in this version of matlab?

Comment: Does the `handles` structure have a field named `image_number` before the set command is executed?

Comment: You could take a look at the following answer:  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54547-getting-reference-to-non-existent-field-error

Comment: The issue is that you don't have an `image_number` field in `handles`

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI need to have a uicontrol or a member of name "image_number". You probably don't have this control as part of GUI.
If your intention is to create a control named "image_number" dynamically, use function "uicontrol" to do so.

The issue is not due to MATLAB version R2011A.